# Are third party solutions really that superior to BCS?

Tags: 2010, bcs, external-list, sql

Let us assume it is my task to establish a **bidirectional connection** between a SharePoint List and a **SQL-database**. According to [Paolo Pialorsi's Developer Manual for SharePoint 2010](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9783866455450.do), BCS (*Business Connectivity Services*) is the right thing to use here.

I also came across the Layer2 BDLC (*Business Data List Connector*). The Vendor claims his Product to be more efficient then BCS due to several Points mentioned in a [long list of advantages](http://www.layer2solutions.com/en/community/FAQs/BDLC/Pages/Feature-comparision-sharepoint-external-list.aspx). One of the main arguments being that BDLC does not require any programming.

My question is, would this kind of thrid party solution really make me solve my task more efficient? Or would I miss any possibilities by not being able to solve things programmatically?

I hope this will not get marked as **not constructive** as I am very new to SharePoint and just want to get some advice from more experienced members.

Comment: I don't know enough about your business requirements for your project, so I can't say whether Layer2's BDLC is more effective, but you can write no-code BCS external content types in SharePoint Designer.  Then, you can create an external list off of that external content type.  It all depends on what you need to do with the data as to whether a third-party solution is necessary or not.